# Manipulating JSON: From basic JSON to more complex JSON with arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to use AJAX to get a list of Styles from my database. The Styles have a Category FK that I want to use to sort the Styles into a JSON object and then use that JSON with JavaScript to populate a Select list based on the Category chosen by the user.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var styles = {
        "cat1": [],
        "cat2": [],
        "cat3": [],
        "cat4": []
    }

    $.getJSON("/Inventory/GetStyles", function (data) {
        $(data).each(function (i, d) {
            var n = {
                "StyleID": d.StyleID,
                "Name": d.Name,
                "CategoryID": d.CategoryID
            };

            switch (d.CategoryID) {
                case 1:
                    styles.cat1.push(n);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    styles.cat2.push(n);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    styles.cat3.push(n);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    styles.cat4.push(n);
                    break;
            };
        });
    });

    alert(styles.cat1[0].Name);
});
```

When I use `debugger;` and step through, I see that everything seems to be working just fine. `styles` is filled with data as expected but the alert never goes off. Instead, I get an error:

**TypeError: styles.cat1[0] is undefined**

This is confusing because, when debugging, I can mouse over and see that `styles.cat1[0].Name` has the value it should. Oddly, however, this only works when I put the `debugger;` statement inside my AJAX call, as seen here:

[image: example a]

If I move the `debugger;` statement to outside the AJAX call, the `styles.cat1[0].Name` changes to undefined, as seen here:

[image: example b]

I am at a loss as to how to get this straight. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no arrays in JSON, it's a format for strings and you probably have javascript objects ?

Comment: Ajax is async. The alert happens before the ajax call finishes.

Comment: Can I suggest `styles['cat'+d.CategoryID].push(n)` rather than that switch statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to AJAX so, though I am aware of its asynchronous nature, I was totally not even thinking about it. I was thinking I was manipulating the data incorrectly or something (hence the way I worded the question). I facepalmed so, ya.. Thanks for quick replies! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to access styles.cat1[0] before the ajax call has been finished. move the alert line up into callback function

```
$.getJSON("/Inventory/GetStyles", function (data) {
        $(data).each(function (i, d) {
            var n = {
                "StyleID": d.StyleID,
                "Name": d.Name,
                "CategoryID": d.CategoryID
            };

            switch (d.CategoryID) {
                case 1:
                    styles.cat1.push(n);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    styles.cat2.push(n);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    styles.cat3.push(n);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    styles.cat4.push(n);
                    break;
            };
        });
        alert(styles.cat1[0].Name);
    });
```

Comment: Ah! I feel so dumb... asynchronous means asynchronous... who would have imagined? ;) Thanks Alex!

Comment: happens ;) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your `alert()` happens before the Ajax request even returns.

This means `alert()` must be part of the `success` callback function. To make this easier you really should get into using jQuery's *deferred* callback paradigm.

It's a lot more straightforward than cramming everything into a single callback function. Compare:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Inventory/GetStyles")
    .then(function (data) {
        var styles = {};
        $.each(data, function (i, d) {
            var catN = "cat" + d.CategoryID;

            if (!(catN in styles)) {
                styles[catN] = [];
            }

            styles[catN].push({
                StyleID: d.StyleID,
                Name: d.Name,
                CategoryID: d.CategoryID
            });
        });
        return styles;
    })
    .done(function (styles) {
        alert(styles.cat1[0].Name);
    });
});
```

Recommended reading http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this example and the link. :)

Comment: Also note that your use of `$(data).each(...)` is wrong. It must be `$.each(data, ...)`.